# ImmutableJS with Redux's combineReducers

Tags: redux, immutable.js

Getting warning: "Using Maps as children is not yet fully supported" when combining reducers (each with its own immutable.js Map) with #redux combineReducers.  What's a better store structure to avoid this?

```
import reducer_2 from './action_handlers/two';
import reducer_3 from './action_handlers/three';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

let reducer = combineReducers({
    reducer_2,
    reducer_3
});

export default reducer;

//=====================
// ./action_handlers/two.js

const INITIAL_STATE_2 = new Map({
    foo: 'bar'
});
export default function reducer_2(state = INITIAL_STATE_2, action) {...}

//======================
// ./action_handlers/three.js

const INITIAL_STATE_3 = new Map({
    baz: 'bat'
});
export default function reducer_3(state = INITIAL_STATE_3, action) {...}

//=======================
```

Comment: did you solve this problem, if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re using [ES6’s Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of Immutable’s.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following line of code in both your reducers:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
```

and then

```
const INITIAL_STATE_2 = Map({
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

Or you can use

```
import Immutable from 'immutable';
const INITIAL_STATE_2 = Immutable.Map({
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear whether you are relating your question to the Immutable.js Map data structure or to the regular Map object.

However, in both cases Redux's `combineReducers` creates a plain object as root-state. If you are using Immutable.js, there exists the [redux-immutable](https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable) package which provides a `combineReducers` function that returns an Immutable.js data structure instead of an object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't user combine reducer of redux
a combineReducers function that comes with Redux will not work as it doesn’t know how to read and create new versions of state.